# Save image in directory after capturing from web page (php)

Tags: javascript, php, image

this is my code and its working.
but i want to to save the captured jpeg file in directory.

please help

this is my code and its working.
but i want to to save the captured jpeg file in directory.

please help

```
<!-- First, include the Webcam.js JavaScript Library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../webcam.js"></script>

<!-- Configure a few settings and attach camera -->
<script language="JavaScript">
    Webcam.set({
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        image_format: 'jpeg',
        jpeg_quality: 90
    });
    Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
</script>

<!-- A button for taking snaps -->
<form>
    <input type=button value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
</form>

<!-- Code to handle taking the snapshot and displaying it locally -->
<script language="JavaScript">
    function take_snapshot() {
        // take snapshot and get image data
        Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
            // display results in page
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 
                '<h2>Here is your image:</h2>' + 
                '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
        } );
    }
</script>
```

[full source code](https://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/)

Comment: have you finished reading the [manual](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs) ?, there is provided to upload captured image, so you can save captured image in a directory with upload to your server and save it.